# cursors within cursors for Auto_Fix users

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursors

I have the below script and I want to be able to run this against a dynamic list of databases except the system databases.  That's straight forward enough.  The tricky bit is each database could have a different list of users to run the fix command against.  Would this be a 3rd cursor?  My attempt below which is not properly populating the users for each database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SET nocount ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
--
-- Declare and define variables
--

DECLARE @databasename VARCHAR(50) -- database name
DECLARE @sqlcommand nvarchar(256) -- SQL Command generated
```

### -- Include the in-scope database names into @name

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT NAME
  FROM   master.dbo.sysdatabases
  WHERE  NAME NOT IN ( 'master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb', 'DBATools' ) -- don't include the databases
OPEN db_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @databasename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      PRINT 'Fixing Logins for '
            + Cast(@databasename AS VARCHAR)

      DECLARE curSQL CURSOR FOR
        SELECT "USE " + ( @databasename ) + ";" + " exec sp_change_users_login 'AUTO_FIX','" + NAME + "'"

      SELECT NAME
      FROM   sys.sysusers
      WHERE  issqluser = 1
             AND NAME NOT IN ( 'dbo', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys' )

      OPEN curSQL

      FETCH curSQL INTO @sqlcommand

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT @sqlcommand
            EXEC (@sqlcommand)
            FETCH curSQL INTO @sqlcommand
        END

      CLOSE curSQL
      DEALLOCATE curSQL

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @databasename
  END

CLOSE db_cursor

DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: I think you should add the specific database tag to your question. My guess is SQLServer ?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing with your procedure is that, unlike PHP, TSQL cannot use single and double quotes interchangeably. So I fixed up your dynamic SQL string.

The other minor thing appears to have been a disjointed query from the cursor declaration - in yours, you follow the second declare with a select clause, without an accompanying from clause, which would have thrown on "Name" not being able to be found for that cursor. So I fixed that up, too.

```
DECLARE @databasename SYSNAME, @sqlcommand nvarchar(max)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT NAME
    FROM   master.dbo.sysdatabases
    WHERE  NAME NOT IN ( 'master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb', 'DBATools' ) -- don't include the databases
OPEN db_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @databasename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Fixing Logins for '
    + Cast(@databasename AS VARCHAR)

    DECLARE curSQL CURSOR FOR
        SELECT 'USE ' + @databasename + ';' + ' exec sp_change_users_login ''AUTO_FIX'',''' + NAME + ''';'
        FROM   sys.database_principals
        WHERE  Type='S'
            AND NAME NOT IN ( 'dbo', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys' )

    OPEN curSQL

    FETCH curSQL INTO @sqlcommand

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @sqlcommand
        --EXEC (@sqlcommand)
        FETCH curSQL INTO @sqlcommand
    END

    CLOSE curSQL
    DEALLOCATE curSQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @databasename
END

CLOSE db_cursor

DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

EDIT: Switched table to database_principals rather than sys.sysusers per comment.

Comment: thank you.  There is a problem with this as per what I have tried as well.  If you run this you will notice the user accounts for every database are as per the database currently selected in the database drop down list in ssms.  The users to be fixed are different for each database in turn.  The script needs to be able to enumerate the users for each database and then insert them in to the fix string.  Can you try this and let me know what you think.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, then you'll want sys.database_principals, not sys.sysusers.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it cursorless.

```
DECLARE @Output NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Output = ''

SELECT @Output = @Output +
'--Fixing Logins For ' + name + CHAR(10) + 
'USE ' + name + CHAR(10) + 
'EXEC sp_change_users_login ''AUTO_FIX'','''+
(
    SELECT  b.name 
    FROM   sys.sysusers as b
    WHERE  issqluser = 1
    AND b.name NOT IN ( 'dbo', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys' )
)
+''''+CHAR(10)+CHAR(10)

FROM  master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE  NAME NOT IN ( 'master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb', 'DBATools' )
PRINT @Output
```